# Second object of each pair must be non-nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Iam working on app and when i debug my code it is showing the following error.

```
-(IBAction)addSelected:(id)sender
{

    NSString* emptyStr = @"";

    NSDictionary* traits = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        self.walletName.text,       @"alias",
        self.abc.text,     @"abc",
        self.field.text,     @"field",
        @"name,"                @"Type",
        nil];-------at this point it is showing thread recieved signal sigabrt
```

In the debug cosole it is gving this reason.
'+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 6):

`@"name,"                @"Type",`  should be `@"name",                @"Type",`

The `,` is inside the string.

Comment: Hey thanks deepak It worked fine.But iam getting an exception error as  +[CheckItem phonenumber]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x120914'
in this method +(CheckItem*)initWith:(NSDictionary*)traits
{
    CheckItem* check = [[CheckItem new] autorelease];
    NSEnumerator* e = [[traits allKeys] objectEnumerator];
    NSString* key = nil;
    while ( (key = [e nextObject]) )
        [self performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(key) withObject: [traits objectForKey: key]]; 
    return check;
}
where i had many properties like name,email but it is throwing the exception at phone number only.

Comment: I can help you with that but it's a completely different problem from this so a new question would be the right way to go based on the FAQ. Also when you're putting the question, add the crash log and code where you are getting the error.

Comment: Since you are doing `[self performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(key) withObject: [traits objectForKey: key]];` in a class method, `self` represents the class and not the object. So you need to have the methods represented by the keys as class methods and not instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSDictionary* traits = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        self.walletName.text,       @"alias",
        self.abc.text,     @"abc",
        self.field.text,     @"field",
        @"name",                @"Type", nil];
```

The problem is form @"name,".

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was doing this:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [today timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictExpiryDate =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:currentTime, KEY_4_VALUE_OF_EXPIRY_DATE, nil];
```

The problem here is currentTime, i replaced currentTime as followed:

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentTime]
```

This solved my issues.