# second object of each pair must be non-nil. Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

Here is my code

```
NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableDictionary * myData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[myData setValue:@"151" forKey:@"LoginID"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"UserID"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"SubUserID"];
[myData setValue:@"92" forKey:@"WorkGroupID"];
[myData setValue:@"Doctor" forKey:@"WorksFor"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"UserWorkGroup"];

[myArray addObject:myData];

myData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[myData setValue:@"," forKey:@"SortingName"];
[myData setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Searching"];
[myData setValue:@"Desc" forKey:@"SortingOrder"];
[myData setValue:@"10" forKey:@"RecordsCount"];
[myData setValue:@"0" forKey:@"PageIndex"];
[myArray addObject:myData];

NSData *dataToSend = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataToSend encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[getProfileServices sendSynchronousPostRequestWithStringForAction:getProfileURL andParameters:[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonString ,nil]andRequestType:@"POST"];
```

when i run this am getting this error

> `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: `-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:]:` second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what the problem is: you have `initWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonString ,nil` - the error message states *second object of each pair must be non-nil*!

Comment: i tried with that also but no use

Comment: why is `andParameters` expecting a dictionary, what's it used for? why are you passing json?

Comment: What have you *tried*??? You simply need to fix the compile error.

Comment: i tried with removing nil but showing missing sentinel in  method dispatch

Answer (score 0):

In `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` set string value and string keys. Example:
the below example is correct format,

[myData setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Searching"];

> don't send nil value and nil key.
>
> don't send the **,** inside value  in dictionary

your mistake is given below

```
[myData setValue:@"," forKey:@"SortingName"];
```

above problem is **","**

change the code is below,

```
[myData setValue:@"String Value" forKey:@"SortingName"];
```

or

please change the below code,

```
[getProfileServices sendSynchronousPostRequestWithStringForAction:getProfileURL andParameters:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dataToSend] andRequestType:@"POST"];
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Your answer is not really understandable - what should OP change in your opinion, what would fix the problem for him?

Comment: setting value with only comma(Here the "," is the string only) is problem according to you ? i don't think so.

Comment: Yes **,** is not send the dictionary values, and my above code is clearly update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345637/second-object-of-each-pair-must-be-non-nil see the example

Comment: what is `getProfileServices`?

Comment: i have update the answer please change and its helpful