# second object of each pair must be non-nil. Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?' when adding row count

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm getting exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'

In this code:

```
if ([[questionaireDic objectForKey:@"Answer6Option"] boolValue]) {
    NSArray *ans6Arr = [subQuestionaireArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"QuestionNo = 6 AND SortOrder = 1"]];
    int rowCount = 1;
    for (int i =0;i<ans6Arr.count ; i++) {
        NSDictionary *ans6Dic = ans6Arr[ i];
        NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell1TextDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"810-L50-%d",rowCount,@"DataId",[ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell1Text"],@"Value", nil];
        [questionaireArr addObject:answer6Row1Cell1TextDic];

        NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell2DateDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"820-L50-%d",rowCount,@"DataId",[ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell2Date"],@"Value", nil];
        [questionaireArr addObject:answer6Row1Cell2DateDic];

        NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell3NumberDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"830-L50-%d",rowCount,@"DataId",[ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell3Number"],@"Value", nil];
        [questionaireArr addObject:answer6Row1Cell3NumberDic];

        if (![[ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell4Number"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell4NumberDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"840-L50-%d",rowCount,@"DataId",[ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell4Number"],@"Value", nil];
            [questionaireArr addObject:answer6Row1Cell4NumberDic];
        }
        rowCount++;
    }
```

I have tried the fixes in [Second object of each pair must be non-nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345637/second-object-of-each-pair-must-be-non-nil?rq=1) and [Second object of each pair must be non-nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345637/second-object-of-each-pair-must-be-non-nil) .And several examples.But none of that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception arises due to string with format specifier. You should enclose both **@"810-L50-%d",rowCount** values into one string. Otherwise, it takes **@"810-L50-%d"** as object value for key **rowCount**.

So, the key and value should be changed to

```
NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell1TextDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"810-L50-%d",rowCount], @"DataId",[ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell1Text"],@"Value", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it can sometimes help to reformat code for legibility...

If you change this line:

```
NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell1TextDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"810-L50-%d",rowCount,@"DataId",[ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell1Text"],@"Value", nil];
```

to:

```
NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell1TextDic =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"810-L50-%d", rowCount,
 @"DataId", [ans6Dic objectForKey:@"Cell1Text"],
 @"Value", nil
 ];
```

You will see that you have a `nil` key for the object `"Value"` ... which, I'm pretty sure, was not your intent.

Note: I think you also have your objects and keys reversed...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to produce a string from a format, `@810-L50-%d`, and value, `rowCount` *without actually calling a string formatting method to do that. Because of this your list of values and keys gets out of sync and the compiler reports the error relating to `nil`.

Switching to modern syntax and correcting this gives:

```
NSDictionary *answer6Row1Cell1TextDic =
   @{ @"DataId" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"810-L50-%d",rowCount],
      @"Value" : ans6Dic[@"Cell1Text"]
    };
```

The `@{ ... }` syntax is a *dictionary literal* and contains zero or more `<key> : <value>` pairs. The `ans6Dic[@"Cell1Text"]` is *dictionary indexing* which looks up the value matching a key.

HTH